# Can I buy a GPU from a grant money and put it into my personal computer?

Tags: ethics, funding

In my department each person gets a fixed amount of money to spend to buy a computing technology. Usually people here spends it on MacBooks and Apple screens. I bought myself a better laptop for less money and I am not planning to buy an additional screen either, therefore I still have some money in my budget to spend.

I can use some GPU power, however I don't have a working computer to put the card in (only a laptop). I can however, put it into my own (private) computer, and run GPU related jobs there. Can I do that?

The other option is to buy a whole new computer with the card in, which would cost more of the public money.

Of course I won't sell it, and give it back after the end of my contract, if they ask me to, however it would be probably obsolete at that point.

Comment: Ask your grant manager.

Comment: @henning If this is public funding it's not even worth asking. The answer will be "no".

Comment: @Roland if it's an external GPU, there's no problem. The GPU stays property of the lab, and as it's external, it doesn't matter on which computer you use it. You could even add it to the laptop. As long as you use it for the work it's intended. But personally I find it a waste of money to put extra GPU on a laptup unless you can interface it through something like Thunderbolt.

Comment: @JorisMeys Doesn't sound like an external GPU. Also, using private equipment on the job isn't allowed in many places (although some do allow it).

Comment: To the user who raised the close flag, I fail to see how this question is off-topic. Would you please explain?

Comment: @Roland It doesn't, so I mentioned the option. You're right about private equipment, but that's dependent on his institute. I am allowed to do that for example. I'm actually doing it (or was doing it before I took a break and will do so after I finished this comment :-) )

Comment: Could you look into using cloud services (e.g. the Amazon cloud)? This will avoid the conflict of interest entirely, although its suitability will depend on the work you're doing. If you intend to use the GPU for personal use as well (e.g. gaming) then you should make sure that personal use is explicitly allowed.

Comment: Depending on where you live, you might not even be able to buy the GPU in the first place. At least at my institution (in Europe), things like that usually have to be bought for a specific (department-owned) computer, not as a standalone item.

Comment: @Roland so I cannot read papers, write work emails and manage my agenda from my phone?

Comment: @user2173836 I suspect that Roland only means that for situations where data privacy is of concern (e.g. a teaching hospital). It would be absurd to forbid a theoretical mathematician from using her personal laptop.

Comment: @user2173836 Ask your manager for the IT regulations. Some institutions do not allow transferring data and software between private and institute hardware. However, installing institute hardware into private computers is a no-go at most places.

Comment: @Roland Your conclusion in your first comment is very quick and not backed up. Certainly not if the country is not known.

Comment: If you are doubting is that because probably is in the ethical limits, so I would just avoid the trouble. Your common sense is hesitating, so better pass this time or get the whole computer with the card in, or a external card.

Comment: One of the issues is, depending on your jurisdiction, your employer has to treat property they let you use for personal use as if it is part of your salary, rather than a business expense, and they could feasibly get in trouble for failing to do this. Realistically, people use company/university computers for personal things like email all the time (even if it is technically not allowed), but installing a piece of hardware into your personal computer is a lot more problematic, because even if you do use it for business purposes it will also be used whenever you do personal things.

Comment: @scaaahu I voted for said close flag, for the reason specified. The answer to this is *entirely* based on national and institutional policy, and does not have a generalizable answer.